# How to add sign in with google to a simple android application?

Tags: android, android-studio, google-signin

I am trying to implement a simple android application using android studio where users can sign in with google. I followed the guide at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating, although I'm not sure if I got the part of "Create an OAuth 2.0 client ID" correctly. However, I need in my application that a user can login either by entering a random email and password, or by a real google account. After following the guide, I proceeded to this one https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in. However, after creating a new login activity and adding the part

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();
```

I have an error that says cannot resolve symbol mGoogleApiClient, and the second this in .enableAutoManage().
I tried to change mGoogleApiClient to GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient but the this problem persisted. Am I doing something wrong mentioned in the guide or is there something extra I should do?
I should also mention that the same problem happened when I added the code to an empty activity, not the predefined loginActivity template, with no success.

Update:
Here is my project level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And my app level build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.karim.tvme"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
}
```

Comment: Please post the content of your project-level build.gradle file and your app-level build.gradle file

Comment: One more question, how did you declare `mGoogleApiClient` variable?

Comment: @BNK I tried to just copy the mGoogleApiClient thinking it was previously declared, then I tried GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
        .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
        .build();

Comment: So pls check your code at import... if `import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;` existed or not, if not, import it

Comment: You can read my sample code at https://github.com/ngocchung/GoogleSignInDemo/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/googlesignindemo/MainActivity.java to check more. If it's still not working, pls tell me, I will check next Monday :)

Comment: Pls note that you don't need Google+, so ignore `.requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_LOGIN))` and `.addApi(Plus.API)` and `// G+` section in my code

Answer (score 0):

I found using BNK's code that I had to implement `GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener` and thus the method `public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult)` although this was not mentioned in the guide. Also the guide didn't mention that we had to declare an attribute `private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;` .
Hope this helps.